# XCART-5 Get Attributes Values in programming and Assigning some other values progmatically

Tags: x-cart

I am working on Xcart-5 website customization. And I created my own module and doing work on that.  I just created some Global Attributes (" As a Plain text ") field  and assign these attributes to some product.  Now I want to access these fields value in programming in the product details page for assigning some other value programatically at run time.

How can I achieve this task. Kindly provide me the solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module you should [decorate](http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Step+3+-+applying+logic+changes) the **\XLite\Model\Attribute** class and extend the **getAttributeValue()** method there.

For instance, if I use a module with developer ID **Tony** and module ID **AttributesDemo**, then I would need to create the **XCartDirectory/classes/XLite/Module/Tony/AttributesDemo/Model/Attribute.php** file with the following content:

```
<?php
// vim: set ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 et:

namespace XLite\Module\Tony\AttributesDemo\Model;

/**
 * Attribute
 * @MappedSuperClass
 */
abstract class Attribute extends \XLite\Model\AttributeAbstract implements \XLite\Base\IDecorator
{
    public function getAttributeValue(\XLite\Model\Product $product, $asString = false)
    {
        $result = parent::getAttributeValue($product, $asString);

        if (!$asString) {
            foreach ($result as $obj) {
                if ($obj->asString() == 'Mac') {
                    $obj->getAttributeOption()->setName('Windows');
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Such implementation will change *Mac* values to *Windows* ones in all attributes.

Comment: Lets say, i have a size attribute.
How can i get its multiple values using xcart function. ? 
Please help.

Comment: How to fetch all attributes of a specific product ?

Comment: Hi, have a look at the following article:
https://devs.x-cart.com/basics/basics-of-working-with-product-attributes.html

It should give you an overview of working with product attributes

Comment: Hi Tony. I tried $this->getProduct()->getAttributes(). But its showing empty array even if its not empty. What might be the cause ?

Comment: Two questions:
1) Did you try installing the demo module from the article? Does it work for you?
2) What area you are trying to display attribute info in?

Comment: There is **no** `AttributeAbstract` class in my version of X-Cart (5.3.6.0) + this does **not** answer the original question which was: how do you list a product's **Global Attributes**.

Comment: The original question is 4 years old. I guess it is better to start a new thread and discuss your task there.